# Why does planet's mass affect it's speed around sun?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, newtonian-gravity, orbital-motion, inertial-frames, celestial-mechanics

Let's assume that planet orbits sun with a perfect circular orbit. If force by which sun pulls planet is $\frac{GM_1m_2}{r^2}$, and $F=ma$ than $a = \frac{GM_1}{r^2}$. Now we also know that for circular motion: $a = \frac{V^2}{r}$ , which means that $V = \sqrt{\frac{rGM_1}{r^2}}$ So from this equations it seems that mass of the planet shouldn't matter at all. But I know that mass of the planet does matter if it's quite large, how? why? I mean are this laws incorrect? or do I miss something?

Comment: -1 Not clear. *But I know that mass of the planet does matter if it's quite large, how? why?*  If you know that the mass of the planet does affect its speed, it is up to you to explain why. You have explained why it doesn't depend on mass. What is your explanation for why it does depend on mass?

Comment: Are you trying to play a mind game or you're interested in answer or do you have an answer? I don't understand what do you complain about, it's obvious that I don't know why but I know that it does. If I did know why it does I wouldn't be asking this question.

Comment: You said that you know the mass of the planet does matter. I am asking you to explain how you know (or why you think) mass does matter "if it is large". I cannot read your mind. You have to explain what you are thinking. I cannot provide an appropriate answer unless I understand why you think mass matters.

Answer (score 0):

Probably because in the system "Sun-planet" the planet's orbit has a focus in the center of mass of the system, not in the center of mass of the Sun, although the difference is relatively small because the mass of the planet is much less than the mass  of the Sun.

Comment: do you mean that in that case "r" would be distance between planets center and barycenter? I don't see other way how this equations could be correct and mass of planet still would have effect.

Comment: @cannabis_Grower : Yes.

Comment: @cannabis_Grower - This answer is incorrect.

Comment: @DavidHammen: Could you please explain?

Comment: @akhmeteli - Using the distance to the barycenter in Newton's law of gravity yields an incorrect result.

Comment: @DavidHammen: But I did not use "the distance to the barycenter in Newton's law of gravity", although I admit that my short "yes" left space for misunderstanding. The "r" in the expression "a=V^2/r" is though indeed the distance to the barycenter. However, the "r" in the expression for the acceleration "a" is still the distance between the Sun and the planet.

Comment: That is exactly the incorrect result to which I was referring. Do the math.

Comment: @DavidHammen: With all due respect, I am not going to "do the math" until you explain which "result" is incorrect and why (my last comment considers at least two "results"). On the other hand, I admit that my words left space for misunderstanding  again. When I wrote "the "r" in the expression for the acceleration "a" is still the distance between the Sun and the planet" I meant the expression for "a" from the Newton's law a=GM_1/r^2 (in the inertial reference frame).

Answer (score 0):

Kepler's laws of planetary motion describe a light planet orbiting a
very large mass (the Sun).   Those laws do not apply to a simple
two-body problem where the bodies are similar in size, because
he wasn't studying data on such a system.

Kepler's laws describe orbits as having velocities over paths
that do not vary with the orbiting mass.  Indeed, only the mass of
the Sun is significant in a Keplerian planet's orbital velocity.

Yes, a very large massive planet has lower orbital velocity than 
if it were small, and that velocity goes with an orbital motion
around the center-of-mass of the system (a 'fixed' point in space).
The formulae as Kepler set them up are approximations that treat the solar
position as the mass center, but for a sufficiently large
object those approximations are not useful.   Orbits aren't exactly
as Kepler describes.   That's because 'r' for the acceleration
formula is to center-of-mass, and 'r' for the gravity force is to
center-of-sun; those are no longer the same.

Comment: A massive planet would have a greater orbital velocity than would a small planet with the same semi-major axis length.

Answer (score 0):

> I mean are this laws incorrect?

Kepler's third law says that the square of the period of a planet is proportional to the cube of the planet's semi-major axis. This law does not account for the mass of the planet. This is not quite correct; the mass of the planet does come into play per Newton's law of gravitation. Note that Newtonian gravity is also incorrect (it disagrees with general relativity), but here the errors are very small, at least in our solar system.

What you are missing is that the Sun accelerates toward the planets. Consider a binary star system with no planets in which the two stars orbit each other slowly. (This rules out the need for general relativity.) The two stars accelerate toward one another due to gravitation, with magnitudes $Gm_1/r^2$ and $Gm_2/r^2$. The magnitude of the relative acceleration of the two stars towards one another thus has magnitude $G(m_1+m_2)/r^2$.

Suppose the two stars orbit one another circularly. This means that $v^2/r = a$, where $a$ is the relative acceleration. The period is $P = \frac{2\pi r}v$, so the square of the period is $P^2 = \frac{4\pi^2 r^2}{v^2} = \frac{4\pi^2 r} a = \frac{4\pi^2}{G(m_1+m_2)}r^3$. It turns out that this is also the case for elliptical orbits, with $r$ becoming the semi-major axis length of the elliptical orbit of one star relative to the other. A more correct version of Kepler's third law is that the square of the period of a planet is proportional to the cube of the planet's semi-major axis and inversely proportional to the sum of the planet's mass and the Sun's mass.